# Print Windows form in c#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to print a form using this code:

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g1 = this.CreateGraphics();
        Image MyImage = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, g1);
        Graphics g2 = Graphics.FromImage(MyImage);
        IntPtr dc1 = g1.GetHdc();
        IntPtr dc2 = g2.GetHdc();
        BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);
        g1.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
        g2.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
        MyImage.Save(@"c:\PrintPage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\PrintPage.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StartPrint(fileStream, "Image");
        fileStream.Close();
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"c:\PrintPage.jpg"))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(@"c:\PrintPage.jpg");
        }
    }
```

But is gives me an error at: MyImage.Save.

The error:

> ExternalException was Unhandled: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Can someone give me a fix for this problem,and explain, why I'am getting this error?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I think you must Save before ReleaseHdc.

Comment: I think [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/eb80fbbe-6b89-4c3d-9ede-88a2b105c714) is more simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    private void btn_print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureScreen();
        printDocument1.Print();
        printDocument1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
    }

    Bitmap memoryImage;

    private void CaptureScreen()
    {
        Graphics myGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        Size s = this.Size;
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
    }


    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage_1(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
    }
```

Add a print_document by dragging it from the toolbox to form. Execute this code, it will work fine.

http://csharpprobsandsoln.blogspot.in/2013/04/print-windows-form-in-c.html

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
```

and in your code, add:

```
PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
```

More info [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/srajlaxmi/printing-windows-form-in-C-Sharp-net/)

Comment: Your answer need proper explanation and formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same task and I have created a class (like printable form).
All you have to do is to inherit your Form from that class and call PrintForm(); method.
Here is the class:

```
public class CustomForm : Form
{
    protected Bitmap _prnImage;
    protected PrintPreviewDialog _prnpreviewdlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    protected PrintDocument _printdoc = new PrintDocument();

    public CustomForm()
    {
        _printdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printdoc_PrintPage);
    }

    protected void PrintForm()
    {
        Form form = this;
        _prnImage = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height);
        form.DrawToBitmap(_prnImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, form.Width, form.Height));
        _printdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        _printdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        _prnpreviewdlg.Document = _printdoc;
        _prnpreviewdlg.ShowDialog();
    }
    protected void printdoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle pagearea = e.PageBounds;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(_prnImage, e.MarginBounds);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_prnImage != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_prnImage, 0, 0);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that interface is a more academic and correct way to do that but in my particular case that solution satisfied me.